# My web page is left without any reaction after the website is launched and the page is locked

Tags: asp.net-core

I have web page and My web page is left without any reaction after the website is launched and the page is locked. Codes are as bellow:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
@inject IReciption _Reception;

<section class="p-top-10 p-bottom-10 bgcolor rtl">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="shortcode_modules">
                    <div class="modules__title">
                        <h3>Reception</h3>
                        @*<h3>RegReception<InfoBoxComponent StrMessage="@Message1"></InfoBoxComponent></h3>*@
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center module--social">
                        <div class="social social--color--filled">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" @bind-value="@StrSerialNumber" placeholder="SerialNumber">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    @if (!IsSaveLoading)
                                    {
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="(() => CheckTheSerial())" style="margin-top:15px;">Testing</button>
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:15px;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i> Searching
                                        </button>
                                    }

                                </li>
                                @if (prodSrCls.Responses.Statue != LosacoWeb.Shared.Enumes.StatueResponse.NoStatus)
                                {
                                    @if (prodSrCls.Responses.Statue == LosacoWeb.Shared.Enumes.StatueResponse.Success)
                                    {
                                        <br />
                                        <li><h4><b class="primary">Group:</b> @prodSrCls.GoodsGroupItem_Name</h4></li>
                                        <br />
                                        <li><h4><b class="primary">Model:</b> @prodSrCls.Goods_GoodsName </h4></li>
                                    }
                                    @if (prodSrCls.Responses.Statue == LosacoWeb.Shared.Enumes.StatueResponse.Failed)
                                    {
                                        <br />
                                        <li>
                                            <h3>
                                                <span class="danger icon-close"></span><b class="danger">
                                                    Serial Is not Correct
                                                </b>
                                            </h3>
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end .col-md-6 -->
        </div>
        <!-- end .row -->
    </div>
    <!-- end .container -->
</section>
```

And C# Programming Code Part Is As Bellow:

```
public bool IsSaveLoading = false;
    private string serial;
    public String StrSerialNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return serial;
        }
        set
        {

            serial = value;
             TextChangedEvetFotCleaning();
        }
    }
ProdSerialClasses prodSrCls
            = new ProdSerialClasses();
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ProdSerialClasses> OnFindSerial { get; set; }
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        IsSaveLoading = false;
    }
```

My answer is that how I can resolve my problem. I have to use this code in a online shop project. My other pages work fine. but this page become lock after run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hi. Change second part to :**

```
public bool IsSaveLoading = false;
public String StrSerialNumber = "0";
ProdSerialClasses prodSrCls = new ProdSerialClasses();
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<ProdSerialClasses> OnFindSerial { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    IsSaveLoading = false;
}
```

you must add value to you variable `StrSerialNumber = "0"` because in can cause of error with null value.
I hope your code problem is solved this way.
You should also check for prolapse before using `prodSrCls`. If it is not null, you can use it. If you do not bet, you may still get the error.

```
@if(prodSrCls != null)
{
   // your codes . . .
}
```

Please do not forget to confirm the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I will put your code in my project and I will let you know if I have a problem. If the code works, I will confirm your answer.

Comment: Yes . Your code solved my problem. I have only one question. Why we should check the value of null at the beginning of the code. Why if we do not check, the screen freezes and nothing else can be done?

Comment: Take a look at: https://www.google.com/search?q=trouble+with+null+value+.net+core+webassembly&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIR983IR983&ei=gqahYtHLE4eVxc8PzuuUyAQ&oq=trouble+with+null+value+.net+core&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYADIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgATIICCEQHhAWEB06BAgAEEc6CgghEB4QDxAWEB06BAghEBU6BwghEAoQoAFKBAhBGABKBQhAEgExSgQIRhgAUKcVWPQoYKQ2aABwAngAgAGfAogB2BGSAQMyLTmYAQCgAQHIAQLAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz